# Are there any techniques for manufacturing exosomes in the lab?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, cell-culture

I'm interested in the idea of using exosomes as an alternative transfection agent / delivery mechanism for gene editing applications (CRISPR/cas9, etc).

Information on the matter is sparse.. Does anyone know of any practical techniques for manufacturing exosomes in the lab?

Comment: *Information on the matter is sparse* You can search for any paper that studies exosomes and they'll describe how they obtained them. Is there something specific you cannot find?

Comment: "Manufacturing" in the sense of isolation for research or as a clinical product? Current production methods involve multiple ultracentrifugation, filtration and wash steps followed by detection by immunoassay with culture supernatants as a starting material. In other words, you need an ultracentrifuge. There are small-scale kits for exosome isolation but there's a lot of contaminants often times. Try [this](http://journals.lww.com/immunotherapy-journal/Abstract/2017/04000/Use_of_Engineered_Exosomes_Expressing_HLA_and.1.aspx) publication if you can. Wolters-Kluwer/Ovid are hard to access IMO.

Comment: @canadianer isolation is not easy for exosomes of certain cell types like cardiomyocytes, where you'd need direct access to a heart. And many cells often only accept exosomes that are specific to those cell types. In light of this problem, it would be desirable to have a way to manufacture or synthesize exosomes tailor made to certain cell types. That's really what I'm looking for. Techniques for synthesis rather than isolation.